# MYSQL: how to remove SIMILAR database rows based on username and timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, sql-delete

I have a database table that I use for logging.  I would like to search the table to find all entries with a particular action on the same day by the same user and only keep one of them.

The column names I think need to be used are:
"activity_action" - where the action sought is 'Daily Website Access'
"user_email" - Looking for the same user on the same day
"activity_timestamp" - where I want to ingnore the time and just check if the action was on the same day

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results. Also, are you looking for a `delete` query or a `select`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a delete statement, here is one way to do it in MySQL:

```
delete t
from mytable t
inner join mytable t1
    on  t1.user_email = t.user_email
    and t1.activity_action = t.activity_action
    and date(t1.activity_timestamp) = date(t.activity_timestamp)
    and t1.activity_timestamp < t.activity_timestamp
where t.activity_action =  'Daily Website Access'
```

This deletes records that have the sought `activity_action` and for which another record with the same action and email, that happened during the same day, and whose timestamp is smaller. In other words, this deletes duplicates par action/user/day while retaining the earliest.

Comment: i strongly recommend writing this as a SELECT statement first, verifying the rows  returned, saving the rows returned as a backup, and then converting the SELECT into a DELETE statement.

Comment: I think you answered my Question perfectly.  My only issue is that the table is so large I cannot run this all at once.  I am trying to break into smaller chunks and on initial tests this does exactly what I need.  Thank you!